# Add the open feature requests view to the list of available views on meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, views, bugs-reqs-tabs

Jeff Atwood [has posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/can-we-please-have-transparency-in-new-code-releases-for-the-so-sites/18042#18042) that he uses the following view as a basis for deciding which features to implement.  I suggest adding this as one of the available view tabs on meta.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request+-status-declined+-status-deferred&sort=votes

Comment: add `-status-completed`

Comment: I just copied his url.  I'm open to better ones.

Answer (score 3):

Just putting an answer on this(so you can accept it) that there is now tabs for "bugs" and "reqs"(which is feature-requests) with these views..

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the view that Jeff meant to post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request+-status-declined+-status-deferred+-status-completed+-status-bydesign&sort=votes

This one for questions tagged **bug** would also be interesting:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug+-status-declined+-status-deferred+-status-completed+-status-bydesign&sort=votes

although you might want to [also exclude status-norepro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug+-status-declined+-status-deferred+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-norepro&sort=votes).