# What is the process for getting an answer to a feature request?

Tags: support, meta

I have a feature request question, but no one came along and said "declined", does that mean it is still up in the air? What is the process. I still think it is worth bringing up, especially after clarification of the question via another persons comment.

Is there a specific process to follow or does my question just disappear into a black hole?

[Original Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16032)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member of the dev team will come by and slap on a nice red status-declined, status-deferred, status-planned or status-completed tag on it.

I couldn't tell you why it hasn't happened yet, I'd assume the devs frequently browse the feature-request tags unless they're too busy as it is.

Comment: Is there a particular timeframe or does it just depend on how much attention a request got?

Comment: See edit. I couldn't tell you how the dev team decides when to start focusing on new requests.

Answer (score 4):

Jeff answered this question extremely well [right here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17923/allow-the-community-to-influence-development-of-so-features-explicitly/17997#17997). Progress is based on the number of votes a request has received. Bug fixes are however a priority over this. Since there is no votes at the moment for your particular request, I don't think it is current in the running for implementation, and the transfer of reputation request have all been declined to date.