# Getting attention for dormant feature requests

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the process for getting an answer to a feature request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18321/what-is-the-process-for-getting-an-answer-to-a-feature-request)

I had an upvote the other day for my old answer to [Search filters by minimum rep, maximum views, maximum answers, etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19659/search-filters-by-minimum-rep-maximum-views-maximum-answers-etc)
However, the original feature request was back in 2009, and 2 years later it doesn't seem to have been looked at by the powers that be - certainly no status tag on it.

So, what's the approved way to get this noticed, for either accept or reject?

Comment: Bounties work sometimes.

Comment: Freehand drawings work other times...

Comment: Also related: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306397)

Answer (score 3):

It was almost certainly looked at.  Having lingered for more than 2 years, being bumped four times, and garnering 36 different votes is a good indicator that either a mod or a dev (the 'powers that be') has looked at it.  The fact that they've ignored it means that they're just waiting for more support.

If you really want it to be looked at, and you think it's still really important, offer a bounty.  Per the [FAQ entry "What if I really want someone to look at my question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

> [Put a bounty on it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties). This costs a little reputation, and requires you to have at least 75 reputation, but it will push your post to [the featured tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) for 7 days and visually distinguish it from other posts. It will definitely get more attention, but we can't guarantee it will necessarily be acted upon.

Comment: it has been bountied. ^_^