# Please add the `bugs` and `reqs` tabs to the Questions page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, homepage, bugs-reqs-tabs, questions-page

These are great tabs, but I never go to the homepage.  Please add these tabs to the Questions page.

Note that on the homepage you can only see a certain amount of these posts.  On the Questions page, you could page through all of them.  So without that capability, you can never see the lower rated posts in that list.

Comment: I noticed Bill [marked that item as "status-completed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18130/), but I was wondering where they actually put those views...

Comment: @ccornet, I only found out about it through the blog.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it's ironic that the team doesn't use FogBugz for tracking these bugs and feature requests?

Comment: @Lance: I found out about it through the blog too.  @ccornet: @tvanfosson left a comment there (on the blog) asking that his question be marked completed.  The tabs are only visible from the meta home page.

Comment: @Bill Ahaha, sorry, I meant "I was wondering" as in "I was wondering up until Lance posted this". It makes sense for the item to be marked status-completed: the request is, after all, completed.

Comment: +1 even though I pretty much only use the home page and hardly ever use the Questions page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that sort orders are used on the question pages (except for featured) and filters are used on the home page.

I think the bigger problem is that the UI kind of needs a way to better reflect that an options is a "sort order" or a "filter" and allow you to choose 1 of each.

For example you may want to sort reqs by views, votes, active and so on. (which you can if you filter by tag. But you can not if you filter from the home page.

Now... to complicate things, say you choose reqs on the question pages and next click new, does it clear the "req" filter or keep it? (neither answer is correct)

Comment: I was actually just thinking about the sort/filter thing and wondering how I could easily get the Reqs tab with the Newest sort order, and realized I couldn't (easily).  I've been trying to think up a feature-request involving a UI that would deal with it, but haven't got it pinned down yet.

Answer (score 2):

No need -- you can already perform these queries if you know what the tags are.

The **'reqs' tab** is the same as questions

- tagged [feature-request]
- not tagged [status-completed], [status-declined], [status-deferred]

.. ordered by votes

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request%2b-status-completed%2b-status-declined%2b-status-deferred&sort=votes

The **'bugs' tab** is the same as questions

- tagged [bug]
- not tagged [status-completed], [status-declined], [status-deferred], [status-bydesign]

.. ordered by votes

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug%2b-status-completed%2b-status-declined%2b-status-deferred%2b-status-bydesign&sort=votes

I kept trying to educate people about this stuff, but since nobody seemed to get it..

- [Allow the community to influence development of SO features explicitly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17923/allow-the-community-to-influence-development-of-so-features-explicitly/17997#17997)
- [Monthly Summary of What's New](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new/47437#47437)
- [Why are there so many high-voted requests with status-declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36288/why-are-there-so-many-high-voted-requests-with-status-declined/36292#36292)
- [Can we please have transparency in new code releases for the SO sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/can-we-please-have-transparency-in-new-code-releases-for-the-so-sites/18042#18042)
- [Encouraging feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17985/encouraging-feature-requests/17998#17998)
- [Add a "what's new" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34739/add-a-whats-new-feature/34756#34756)

.. I thought we should **make it a part of the homepage UI** instead.

Comment: Wouldn't this be `status-completed` not `status-declined`....

Comment: Hmmmm, the titles of 4 out of 6 in the above list are about finding things that have been completed... ;-)